# How can I solve 0x80070585 Error code on my Python Flask wfastcgi app?

Tags: iis, python, wsgi, flask

I'm trying to deploy a Flask app on IIS (usually doing it on an Nginx/Gunicorn stack).

### My stack

I'm working with Python 3.7 installed globaly, IIS 10 on Windows 10 pro.

### What I tried

- Activating CGI service on IIS
- Installing wfastcgi from https://pypi.org/project/wfastcgi/
- Enabling wfastcgi with `wfastcgi enable` (and saved the output for the config file)
- Deploying my app on `wwwroot/myapp`
- Adding a `web.config` file on that `myapp` folder that looks like this:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Python FastCGI"
           path="*"
           verb="*"
           modules="FastCgiModule"
           scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe|C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py"
           resourceType="Unspecified"
           requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <appSettings>
    <!-- Required settings -->
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="backend.wsgi.socketio" />
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

`socketio` is the name of my Flask app, everything is ok when I run the wsgi file "standalone".

- Creating an app in IIS linked to that folder with the right physical path

  > while testing app parameters, authentication step is OK, Authorization step raise a warning but not an error.

### Result

When I try to reach my app I get a 500 HTTP error with the folowing 0x80070585 IIS error code.

When I "break" my `web.config` file (removing tag close for example), IIS tell me that the file is not well formed, so the file is reachable.

Since the error seems to come from the scriptProcessor, I double checked that both `C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe` and `C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py` existed. 
May IIS have access troubles?

I tried to inspect IIS logs, but that's not really verbose. I only have HTTP request logs.

Where should I dig to find more logs?

Thank you for yor help, note that I'm totally new to IIS and Microsoft servers, so I may have missed something big.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wfastcgi/info Python on IIS is dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Microsoft seems to give up with this stack, the only serious solution is to switch to an actively maintained solution such as Nginx or Apache. Thanx @Lex Li for the link to the communication.